# Slow Performing Full Screen Menu On Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, css-animations

This is a strange problem that taken a couple of days worth of Googling many 'fixes' but am yet to find a solution to this strange problem. Here goes.

I have a fixed positioned Menu Button at the top of the screen that when clicked simply allows another fixed postion full screen menu to slide down from the top of the screen. Inspired by the solution at this site:

http://gardenestudio.com.br/

here is the css styles for the overlay menu which contains a single child ul as a test.

```
    .overlay{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(59, 69, 97);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translate(0,-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-100%);
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

With the following 'SlideIn' and 'SlideOut' keyframes applied

```
@-webkit-keyframes overlayAnimateIn {
  0% {
  transform: translate(0,-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-100%);
  }

  100% {
  transform: translate(0,0%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes overlayAnimateOut {
  0% {
  transform: translate(0, 0%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0%);
  }

  100% {
  transform: translate(0,-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-100%);
  }
}
```

However, the problem I am having is that on desktop the performance of the animation is fine.
But on mobile devices.. from Sony Xperia Z2 Compact (vanilla install) etc .. the performance of the animation is terrible.. for the first 10 seconds then after that time interval, the animation is smooth as silk. Note: the gardenstudio solution is smooth at all times.

I have gone through a number of optimisations and reductions of my CSS and HTML to try to find what is causing this problem.

looking at the http://gardenestudio.com.br/ example, i have reduced my stylesheet to around 800 lines (the minimum required to render the page correctly) and the HTML markup is 460 Lines (less than gardenstudio)

If I completely reduce the HTML (leaving the css) to virtually nothing, the animation is smooth.
If I reduce the css (leaving the markup) the animation is smooth..

Something tells me that there is something in my markup and/or css that is computationally expensive and causing a bottleneck.

Can anyone suggest any help finding the bottleneck or if there are any other suggested solutions, that would be great :)

Comment: Maybe some background images or gradient? (that's the only thing that comes to my mind that disappear when CSS or Markup is removed)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I have removed all background images from the CSS and removed all images or anything that may cause more requests.

Answer (score 0):

Well after 2 and a half days of reducing, removing and optimising I have found the culprit for now.

We have a body content wrapper that has a **Box Shadow** applied to it.

Removing this Box shadow solved the problem and the animation is now smooth as anything.

I will continue to slowly re-add all the removed styles etc and report back if I find out why this is causing such a major performance hit.